# Update an element in an array object at state by using textInput React Native

Tags: react-native, textinput

What I'm trying to do here is to update the array object 'available' using textInput and below is my code. I don't know why it keeps giving me the token error at the _update function line. Please help. Thank you!

```
export class Inventory extends Component {
state = {
    available: [
        {id: 0, name: 'Xb', value:5},
        {id: 1, name: 'Ad', value:19},
        {id: 2, name: 'Sc', value:1},
        {id: 3, name: 'AV', value:3},
        {id: 4, name: 'Ba', value:8},
        {id: 5, name: 'Ch', value:2},
        {id: 6, name: 'Pr', value:9},
        {id: 7, name: 'Mi', value:10},
        {id: 8, name: 'Se', value:1},
    ],
}

    _update = (text,index) => this.setState({available[index].value: text});

render(){
 index = 0;
  return(
    <View style={styles.container}> 
      <TextInput style={styles.input}
      keyboardType = 'number-pad'
      returnKeyType = 'go' 
      autoCapitalize = 'none'
      maxLength = {3}
      value = {this.state.available[index].value}
      onChange = {(text) => _update(text,index)} />
    </View>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`_update = (text,index) => this.setState({available[index].value: text});` is not valid in a few ways. First, `setState` takes an object that should be the same key and value that is on your state right now if you are updating the value. Second, `available[index].value` does not evaluate to anything because `available` is not defined. You can only access `available` via `this.state.available`. Third, `available[index].value` is gonna be the key on the new component state, which is not what your desired I presume.

Change your update to be something like this

```
_update = (text, index) => {
  const newArray = [...this.state.available];
  newArray[index].value = text;
  this.setState({ available: newArray });
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. What is the `...` the `[...this.state.available]`  ?

Comment: That is called the spread operator. Check this https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_operator for reference. Basically, for array,  a spread operator takes the items in the array and put them in this new array that we are creating.

Comment: I'm trying the same method but it says **Cannot modify managed objects outside of a write transaction.** ... Im working on react native and realm database to populate that array.

Comment: Try following the realm doc and wrap the code that you are using to populate array in a ‘realm.write(() => {...})’ block

Answer (score 2):

Never mutate this.state like you do it directly with the normal javascript way. Actually you should have in mind that this.state is immutable. The best way to go with this:

1- First create the copy of state array.

2- Find index of the item (if index is available skip this one).

3- Update the value of item at that index.

4- Use setState to update the state value.
So in your case you would do something like:

```
 (text,index) => {
   let newArray = [...this.state.available];
     newArray[index] = {...newArray[index], value: text}
   this.setState({available: newArray});
  }
```

Hope this will help you out.